# How to search a string in a whole MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search a specific string from a whole MySQL database not from only a single table of the database and get the data as a JSON object in my android app.

here is my php file

```
 <?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);


$con = require("connection.php");


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

}


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$username,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$id,$name,$phone,$email,$username, $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user[name]= $name;

    $user[phone]= $phone;

    $user[email]= $email;

    $user[username]= $username;

    $user[password]= $password;

}

echo json_encode($user);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);

?
```

But I don't want to search only in user table instead of i want to search in whole database. please help.

Comment: so specify every table and column you want to search

Comment: This seems to be a login script. Why would you search for username and password outside of your user table?

Comment: 1. You should add quotes when using associative arrays `$user['name']`. 2. Are you storing the passwords in the database as unhashed plain text strings? _Never ever ever never do that!_ Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5, you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Shadow bro this is just a sample php code not that what I want... thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are no direct way to SELECT from the whole database. Instead you can get all tables from the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449732/get-all-tables-from-information-schema-mysql).
Then you can loop over all tables and search in [all columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) with the comlumn types like eg. varchar, text or others depending on your needs.

Comment: Giving a client permission to search information_schema? That sounds like a terrible idea. Did you make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: thanks Laris Nielsen for your answer, I found another way to do it. from SQL query i will select my all the table that I need...

Comment: @Takarii, :-S Yeah maybe! :-) I am used to work with virtual machines so it's actually only one user that has access to the db.